# find previous value based on condition postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

```
id    account   amount  
123     abc      10        
1234    abc      12        
4568    abc      16        
456     def      20        
458     def      30
```

i want to filter unique id whose difference(amount) is less than 5 (group by account). Here the answer is like:

```
id:
123
1234
4568
```

Comment: i think its something difficult to acheive

Comment: When you don't know what you should order by, how do you know which one is   `id-1`  ?

Comment: actually i need to find the ids whose amount difference is less than 5.so here the answer are 123,1234 and 4568.we can do order by difference

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I'm asking let's say for a given account is it always a higher id (1234) minus  lower id(123) or does it change other times? How do you know which one is previous. The output from the query does not determine the order.

Comment: ID value doesnt matter .Its the amount (ascending) which does matter. subtract the consecutive amount of particular account. Here amount(1234)-amount(123) = 2.Hence ans is 1234 and 123

Comment: question is edited for more clarity

Comment: Check the answer and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine `LEAD` and `LAG` to get the desired result.

```
SELECT id
FROM (
    SELECT t.*
        ,amount - LAG(amount, 1, 0) OVER (
            PARTITION BY account ORDER BY amount
            ) AS diff1
        ,amount - LEAD(amount, 1, 0) OVER (
            PARTITION BY account ORDER BY amount
            ) AS diff2
    FROM t
    ) s
WHERE abs(diff1) < 5
    OR abs(diff2) < 5;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fd99e0/10)

Comment: marked as right.Thanks a ton.i failed to use the lead and lag function correctly.Just one doubt.what is the third argument in lag/lead function

Comment: @buntysahoo : You should click on the right symbol  √ in order to mark the answer as correct. The 3rd option is the default value (0 here) when next or previous does not exist.